# How to view what query was ran when a form is submitted?

Tags: database

Im using drupal 7, I'm trying to find out where abouts in the database certain values are submitted.

Is it possible to view what sql query was ran after a form was submitted?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this a custom form that you have written or is it a core form (ex. a node/add form)?

Comment: This is from core/contrib, nothing I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Install the devel module https://drupal.org/project/devel, and choose the option display query log. The queries will be shown on the bottom of each page.

In admin/config/development/devel:

Check 'display query log'

Sometimes, I prefer just switching on logging in my.cnf for MySQL, because it shows the complete query as executed. If you do that, do not forget to switch logging off again when you are done. Otherwise, you'll fill up your disk/partition.

In the [mysqld]section, add:

```
log=/var/log/mysqld
```

Restart mysqld.

Comment: Devel query log only shows the queries used to generate the page and won't show the form queries because Form API redirects to this page after processing the insert. Turning on mysql query log is probably a good option as any, short of adding something into core db_query library to log every query using Devel dpq().